# How to resize images to get the same ratio without or with white space

Tags: image, resize, product, edit, bulk

I have about 1000 products images with and without white space all have 3x4 aspect ratio / 302x403 px. How to bulk resize images to get the same ratio without or with white space. I want them to look all the same?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZklGK.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRXGd.jpg)

Comment: Do you have an image-editing tool in mind, and need to know how to use it? If so, please edit your question to explain that. Or are you looking for recommendations for such a tool? If so, requests for software recommendations belong on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Photoshop would be great or with any other easy tool to bulk edit all images would be fine.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. The images are already all 3x4 aspect ratio so what needs to be done? Then you give 2 sample images with no indication of what they are. Are they before and after images? Or 2 images that are incorrect with no indication of what needs doing to them?

Comment: I am sorry that i couldn't explain it on the right way. as you can see the green shirt has a lot of white space and is smaller and is not filling the whole image like the black shirt. i hope this can make it clear now. Thanks